# Converting MPMediaItem to NSData

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, mpmediaitem

I'm trying to convert an MPMediaItem to NSData object so I can play it with AVAudioPlayer.
The following answer was posted a while back on a similar question, with steps on how to to that:

[MPMediaItems raw song data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656124/mpmediapickercontroller-mpmediaitems-and-nsdata/4423880#4423880)

> Of course you can access the data of a
>   MPMediaItem. It's not crystal clear at
>   once but it works. Here's how:
>
> Get the media item's URL from it's
>   MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL property
>   Initialize an AVURLAsset with this URL
>   Initialize an AVAssetReader with this
>   asset Fetch the AVAssetTrack you want
>   to read from the AVURLAsset Create an
>   AVAssetReaderTrackOutput with this
>   track Add this output to the
>   AVAssetReader created before and
>   -startReading Fetch all data with AVAssetReaderTrackOutput's
>   -copyNextSampleBuffer PROFIT!

After fetching the data with 'copyNextSampleBuffer', I now have an CMSampleBufferRef object. How do I continue from here?

Thanks, 
Gili

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)mediaItemToData : (MPMediaItem * ) curItem
{
    NSURL *url = [curItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: url options:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

    exporter.outputFileType =   @"com.apple.m4a-audio";

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * myDocumentsDirectory = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *intervalSeconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f",seconds];

    NSString * fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.m4a",intervalSeconds];

    NSString *exportFile = [myDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportFile];
    exporter.outputURL = exportURL;

    // do the export
    // (completion handler block omitted)
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^{
         int exportStatus = exporter.status;

         switch (exportStatus)
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
             {
                 NSError *exportError = exporter.error;
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportError);
                 break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");

                 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [myDocumentsDirectory
                                                                 stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];

                 //DLog(@"Data %@",data);
                 data = nil;

                 break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown"); break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting"); break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled"); break;
             }
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
             {
                 NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting"); break;
             }
             default:
             {
                 NSLog (@"didn't get export status"); break;
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try to use following code

```
 MPMediaItem *item;
 NSData *dataMedia = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];
```