# Cache ipod-library asset

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ipod

I want to cache a file added from the iPoad library. The url is: ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-8337982997312596354, I just want this file to write to temp/cache folder. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656124/mpmediaitems-raw-song-data) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112925/converting-mpmediaitem-to-nsdata) question on how to get the NSData of the song and then use

> writeToURL:atomically

of NSData to save it. You can get the path of the temp dir of your app with

> NSTemporaryDirectory();