# Converting a NSMediaItem again and again

Tags: nsdata, assets, mpmediaitem, exporter

today I read the first answer on stackoverflow in this thread

[MPMediaItems raw song data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656124/mpmediaitems-raw-song-data)

which was really great. I used it to convert a MPMediaItem to an NSData like the author of the thread wanted it as well. Now there is one thing I don't understand, so maybe you're so kind to help me a little bit? That would be awesome. 
The question is when I choose a song and export it with the code given, it's working fine, but when I then choose another song it exports the first one again. (when I access it outside of the Handler)
Do you know why?
Thanks so much for any help and for giving me your time!
Many greetings,
Tim

Comment: which one did you use among the 2?

Comment: The very first one. Thank you!