# iOS MPMediaPickerController get file data or file url

Tags: ios, media-player, mpmediaitem

I'm looking for a way to get a local file:/// url or a byte stream of audio data for a selected audio file using MPMediPickerController/MPMediaItem.

Anyone know if this is possible? So far it seems impossible based on the documentation I'm reading for MediaPlayer framework.

Answer (score 0):

[MPMediaItems raw song data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656124/mpmediaitems-raw-song-data)

I am struck with the same problem. Please try the above link and let me know if that worked for you.