# Expose music library using http on iOS

Tags: ios

Anybody know how to expose the iPhone music library using a http server on iOS? How do I get the path to the music files on the iPhone?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656124/mpmediaitems-raw-song-data

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
MPMediaItem *item = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
AVURLAsset *song_asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] options:nil];
```